# What Happens When the Hostname Differs from the One in the /etc/hosts File

Tags: linux, dns

It is possible to have the name from `hostname` not appear in the `/etc/hosts` file in *nix systems. What happens in this scenario?

Comment: If the name is available for DNS lookups it may not break things too badly.  But the `hostname` and `/etc/hosts` are all about self identification....

Comment: and if there's no dns there's even an other fallback: [libnss-myhostname](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-myhostname.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, execute the below commands,

Make sure to login as a root and update the hostname entry in this file.

```
cd /etc/sysconfig
vi network
```

Also update `ifcfg-<interface_name>` under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

Once above steps are done just restart the network service (`service networkd restart`).